# ORA-06502 occurs when trying to update column with random data

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to "scrub" some sensitive data from a table by generating a random string that has the exact same number of characters as what was in the column to begin with. The DML follows:

```
UPDATE PROD.SUBMISSION
SET DATA01 = CAST(dbms_random.string('X', LENGTH(DATA01)) AS VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE))
WHERE DATA01 IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(DATA01) > 0
```

When I run this, ORA-06502 is produced.

The DATA01 column is a nullable VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE). I cannot see what the problem is. The table has 100K+ rows, so if anyone can offer suggestions about how to troubleshoot or drill down to the record(s) causing the problem that'd be great.

Regards

Comment: Since `DATA01` is of type VARCHAR2 then `DATA01 IS NOT NULL` and `LENGTH(DATA01) > 0` do the same thing. If `DATA01` was of type VARCHAR and Oracle had actually implemented that type rather than aliasing to VARCHAR2 then those statements would do different things.

Comment: I'm not sure that I see the purpose of the `cast`.  As @MT0 points out, the `WHERE` clause of `data01 is not null` is sufficient for the query.  A non-NULL `varchar2` cannot have a length of 0.

Comment: I've removed the length check and the cast and the error still occurs. Thank you for the responses though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you run `SELECT * FROM v$NLS_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER LIKE 'NLS_%CHARACTERSET';` and post back what character set(s) you are using?

Comment: @MT0:   NLS_CHARACTERSET=WE8ISO8859P1
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET=AL16UTF16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your diligent investigation. I'm not sure what the issue was, but our DBA ran statistics on the table and restarted the server. We then deleted and then re-imported our production data. The DDL I originally posted worked successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to replicate the problem and I haven't found anything which generates an error yet.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6db1/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBMISSION (
  DATA01 VARCHAR2(2000)
);

INSERT INTO SUBMISSION VALUES ( 'X' );
INSERT INTO SUBMISSION VALUES ( 'TEST' );
INSERT INTO SUBMISSION VALUES ( NULL );
INSERT INTO SUBMISSION VALUES ( 'Something longer.' );
INSERT INTO SUBMISSION VALUES ( '!"£$%^&*()_+-={}[];:''@~#,<.>/?\|`¬' );
INSERT INTO SUBMISSION VALUES ( DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X',2000) );

UPDATE SUBMISSION
SET DATA01 = DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', LENGTH(DATA01))
WHERE DATA01 IS NOT NULL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(DATA01,1,60) FROM SUBMISSION
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6db1/3/0)**:

```
|                                          SUBSTR(DATA01,1,60) |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                            U |
|                                                         WSB8 |
|                                                       (null) |
|                                            QNKHK0FVM8A7BO50H |
|                           V3NF2NJQLL5TLHD4HCW1NWDXZPSBVS0OBH |
| CUZSH86NDMX9QQN4DC1DEVTFRXGKEW3INKAVCNZANL53NMU5OW5FJ5X4SFDW |
```

**Edit**

You can run this:

```
UPDATE PROD.SUBMISSION
SET DATA01 = DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', LENGTH(DATA01))
WHERE DATA01 IS NOT NULL
AND   ROWID IN ( SELECT ROWID
                 FROM   ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ) AS RN
                          FROM SUBMISSION )
                 WHERE  RN BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 );
```

If you vary the values in the between clause in the final line then you can try to narrow down which rows are causing the issue.

Comment: On your suggested update to narrow down the problem - you're using the same field to determine the row numbers that is being modified by the update - so the row numbers would change from one execution to the next, and there's no guarantee you wouldn't keep updating the same set of 1,000 rows.

Comment: Well, that will essentially randomly order the rows each time, won't it?  You don't have enough information about the table, but it would be better to divide the rows up by ranges of some other column, such as a primary key.

Comment: @DaveCosta If there is another key then you can use that; however, in all my tests `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NULL )` appears to return the rows numbers in insertion order - this may not always been the case but I've never found a counter example to show this assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging your errors into a separate log table.

Create table and log:

```
19:26:22 (15)HR@sandbox> create table errlog_test (key int primary key, value int not null);

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.06
19:26:49 (15)HR@sandbox> insert into errlog_test values (1,1);

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
19:26:56 (15)HR@sandbox> exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log('errlog_test');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Execute the statement:

```
19:32:05 (15)HR@sandbox> l
  1  update errlog_test set value = null where key = 1
  2* log errors into err$_errlog_test reject limit unlimited
19:32:06 (15)HR@sandbox> /

0 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
```

Note 0 rows updated out of 1. And check the log with record that caused the error:

```
19:32:07 (15)HR@sandbox> select key, value, ora_err_mesg$ from err$_errlog_test;

KEY VALUE ORA_ERR_MESG$
--- ----- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         ORA-01407: cannot update ("HR"."ERRLOG_TEST"."VALUE") to NULL


Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that could correctly be causing this is if the length argument to DBMS_RANDOM refers to length in characters, and the generated string can include multi-byte characters.  This would mean that if you pass 2000 for the length, you might get back a string containing 2000 characters but more than 2000 bytes, and that would not fit into the VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) column.

You could try using a different first parameter to DBMS_RANDOM - perhaps you will just have better luck with a more restricted set of characters.

Another idea for narrowing down the problem would be to run the update for each possible length separately, e.g.:

```
UPDATE PROD.SUBMISSION
SET DATA01 = dbms_random.string('X', LENGTH(DATA01)
WHERE LENGTH(DATA01) = 1
```

And then repeat for 2,3, etc...

If my hypothesis above is correct, you'd probably be successful for smaller lengths and then be more likely to run into errors when you get close to 2000.

Comment: [`DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', len)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i996825) returns uppercase alpha-numeric characters so these should not be multi-byte characters.

Comment: I agree that in the characters sets most commonly used, these character should be single bytes.  But character sets do exist where they would bu multi-byte (e.g. UTF16), and as I say it is the only reason I can think of why the error would be occurring.

Comment: Even if the character set is UTF-16 or UTF-32 the characters produced by `DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X',len)` will all be 1-byte characters (since the `X` option produces uppercase alpha-numeric characters and not code points from the supplementary planes) so the length of the random string will be less than or (at worst) equal to the length of the data prior to update. It cannot take up more bytes than the string it is replacing.